# Heroku error message no Cedar-supported app detected

Tags: heroku, cedar

So, I am running into more problems with heroku and this rails tutorial. The rails tutorial I am making had me develop a super basic app. They then had me create a bit bucket account. After this they had me create a Heroku account. Now they are asking me to push my *origin master* to my heroku host. When I do this, I am getting this error message and I cannot figure it out. Anyone have any hints as to how I could solve this? Thanks so much in advance!

```
alopex@alopex-TH55-HD:~/work-space$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 66, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (55/55), done.
Writing objects: 100% (66/66), 16.39 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 66 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:  !     Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected
remote: HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack
remote:       to use for this application automatically.
remote: See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected
remote: HINT: This occurs when Heroku cannot detect the buildpack
remote:       to use for this application automatically.
remote: See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to safe-badlands-5004.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/safe-badlands-5004.git
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
```

Comment: You need to be in your project folder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I GOT IT! OH LORD I GOT IT!

Ahem...

---

So, Steve and Collin were correct. I did in fact need to be in my project directory so Heroku could sense my Ruby files and proceed accordingly. I goofed up when I pushed my initial app to Bit Bucket. I pushed my app onto Bit Bucket inside of a main directory. This made my app the a subfolder, which in turn made it impossible for Heroku to detect its presence.

The solution was selecting all of my app, click and dragging it to the desktop and deleting the phony main folder. I the proceeded to put my files back into the Bit Bucket repository and add, committed, and pushed it to Bit Bucket.

If this happens to you, make sure that you also drag the hidden folders in your app into your new folder as well, as that could really mess you up.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 14):

You need to `cd` in to your project directory, as I'm assuming `~/work-space` isn't the name of your app.

Do the following: `cd path/to/root/of/your/project` and try the command again.

**UPDATE**

Historically, the more major fix for this has been one of two things:

Correctly naming your `.buildpacks` file (make sure it's not `.buildpack`)

*or*

Reinitializing your `.git` files:

```
rm -rf .git
git init
git add .
git commit -am "Reinitialize"
heroku create --stack cedar
git push heroku master
```

Comment: I've updated my answer to include another variety of fixes.