# Pushing To Heroku Fails - No Such App Fatal

Tags: git, heroku

Git push onto heroku is pointing to a non-existing git repository.

`git.heroku.com/secure-reef-1722.git` this is the repository created when we ran **heroku create** command.

But when we run a 'push' command (**$ git push heroku master**), it says

> remote: !       No such app as boiling-inlet-6957.
>       fatal: repository 'https://git.heroku.com/boiling-inlet-6957.git/' not found

Also we are not able to see the new repository when we run **$ git remote -v**

> ```
> heroku  https://git.heroku.com/boiling-inlet-6957.git (fetch)
> heroku  https://git.heroku.com/boiling-inlet-6957.git (push)
> origin  git@bitbucket.org:coderz$/toy_app.git (fetch)
> origin  git@bitbucket.org:coderz$/toy_app.git (push)
> ```

Now we are unable to push files to the new heroku git repository (git.heroku.com/secure-reef-1722.git)

Kindly help us out. Thanks in advance.

**Complete sequence of commands**

```
coderz$:~/workspace/toy_app (master) $ heroku create
Creating secure-reef-1722... done, stack is cedar-14
https://secure-reef-1722.herokuapp.com/ | https://git.heroku.com/secure-reef-1722.git
coderz$:~/workspace/toy_app (master) $ git push heroku master
remote: !       No such app as boiling-inlet-6957.
fatal: repository 'https://git.heroku.com/boiling-inlet-6957.git/' not found
coderz$:~/workspace/toy_app (master) $ git remote -v
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/boiling-inlet-6957.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/boiling-inlet-6957.git (push)
origin  git@bitbucket.org:coderz$/toy_app.git (fetch)
origin  git@bitbucket.org:coderz$/toy_app.git (push)
coderz$:~/workspace/toy_app (master) $
```

Comment: Solution to this problem is the answer given by 'Collin Graves' to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31330587/heroku-error-message-no-cedar-supported-app-detected)

Answer (score 68):

Try to re-add the remote url.

```
// Check for the current url 
git remote -v

// remove remote url
git remote rm heroku

// re-add the remote url
git remote add heroku git@heroku.com:boiling-inlet-6957.git
```

[image]

Comment: "boiling-inlet-6957.git" we deleted the application associated with this repo on Heroku. So there is no point again adding this repo. We just want new repo to be accepted and the old deleted applications should be flushed.

Comment: Well Swift Guy, then just replace the last part containing boiling-inlet... with git.heroku.com/secure-reef-1722.git. You are just missing the correct remote entry.

Comment: Set the right names, i don't know which is your required name

Comment: April 2020, Still Working very nicely

Comment: Thankssss, this work's for me, salute from colombia

Answer (score 17):

This command solve mine

```
git remote rm heroku
git remote add heroku https://git.heroku.com/app-name.git
```

Answer (score 2):

I am following the next setps:

1. git remote rm heroku
   #remove the remote url
2. git remote add heroku https://git.heroku.com/myapp.git

## add new url heroku remote

3. git remote -v

## I verify the correct url remote

4. git push heroku master

## Pushing the changes

Answer (score 1):

I solved this same issue by running:
heroku login

before running:
git remote add heroku https://git.heroku.com/app-name.git

Answer (score 0):

```
git remote -v
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/falling-wind-1624.git (fetch)
heroku  https://git.heroku.com/falling-wind-1624.git (push)


 heroku git:remote -a falling-wind-1624
```

Comment: Can you explain in words what was wrong with what the poster of this question did, and why the above would solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

> Below solution work for me

1. Check current URL: **git remote -v**
2. Remove current URL: **git remote rm heroku**
3. Set New URL: **git remote add heroku git.heroku.com/<<YOUR_URL>>.git**

Answer (score 0):

1. The first step is to remove the existing link on Heroku

   git remote rm heroku
2. Add the new link on Heroku. (Be careful to follow the exact format of the link below)

   git remote add heroku https://git.heroku.com/app-name.git
3. Test your current codes on Heroku locally

   heroku local web
4. Push all changes to Heroku

   git push heroku main

You should be fine afterwards. Please let me know if your issues persists in the comments below.